# Modify and Implement Query

Tags: sql, t-sql

We are trying to do an analysis of how long our staff have been working on a hourly basis for trending and forecasting purposes.

We have both the clock in (SHIFTA_Start) and clock out (SHIFTA_End) of the employees.

Below is the current code that I am using and I have included the output shown in SQL after execution.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

However when the employee is working overnight eg: SHIFTASTART != SHIFTAEND, the fields cannot be populated. The current SQL only works when the employee start and end shift on the same day.

Does anyone know how to modify the query so that when employee works overnight, it can populate in SQL columns?

```
SELECT 
--b.*,
b.EMPLOYEENAME,
B.DEPARTMENT,

CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(b.SHIFTA_start,17),103) AS SHIFTA_start,
CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(b.ShiftA_End,17),103) as ShiftA_End,
b.StartTime_HOUR,
b.StartTime_min,
b.EndTime_HOUR,
b.EndTime_min,


CASE WHEN b.[0H_START] < b.[0H_END] THEN  b.[0H_START] ELSE b.[0H_END] END AS [0],
CASE WHEN b.[1H_START] < b.[1H_END] THEN  b.[1H_START] ELSE b.[1H_END] END AS [1],
CASE WHEN b.[2H_START] < b.[2H_END] THEN  b.[2H_START] ELSE b.[2H_END] END AS [2],
CASE WHEN b.[3H_START] < b.[3H_END] THEN  b.[3H_START] ELSE b.[3H_END] END AS [3],
CASE WHEN b.[4H_START] < b.[4H_END] THEN  b.[4H_START] ELSE b.[4H_END] END AS [4],
CASE WHEN b.[5H_START] < b.[5H_END] THEN  b.[5H_START] ELSE b.[5H_END] END AS [5],
CASE WHEN b.[6H_START] < b.[6H_END] THEN  b.[6H_START] ELSE b.[6H_END] END AS [6],
CASE WHEN b.[7H_START] < b.[7H_END] THEN  b.[7H_START] ELSE b.[7H_END] END AS [7],
CASE WHEN b.[8H_START] < b.[8H_END] THEN  b.[8H_START] ELSE b.[8H_END] END AS [8],
CASE WHEN b.[9H_START] < b.[9H_END] THEN  b.[9H_START] ELSE b.[9H_END] END AS [9],
CASE WHEN b.[10H_START] < b.[10H_END] THEN  b.[10H_START] ELSE b.[10H_END] END AS [10],
CASE WHEN b.[11H_START] < b.[11H_END] THEN  b.[11H_START] ELSE b.[11H_END] END AS [11],
CASE WHEN b.[12H_START] < b.[12H_END] THEN  b.[12H_START] ELSE b.[12H_END] END AS [12],
CASE WHEN b.[13H_START] < b.[13H_END] THEN  b.[13H_START] ELSE b.[13H_END] END AS [13],
CASE WHEN b.[14H_START] < b.[14H_END] THEN  b.[14H_START] ELSE b.[14H_END] END AS [14],
CASE WHEN b.[15H_START] < b.[15H_END] THEN  b.[15H_START] ELSE b.[15H_END] END AS [15],
CASE WHEN b.[16H_START] < b.[16H_END] THEN  b.[16H_START] ELSE b.[16H_END] END AS [16],
CASE WHEN b.[17H_START] < b.[17H_END] THEN  b.[17H_START] ELSE b.[17H_END] END AS [17],
CASE WHEN b.[18H_START] < b.[18H_END] THEN  b.[18H_START] ELSE b.[18H_END] END AS [18],
CASE WHEN b.[19H_START] < b.[19H_END] THEN  b.[19H_START] ELSE b.[19H_END] END AS [19],
CASE WHEN b.[20H_START] < b.[20H_END] THEN  b.[20H_START] ELSE b.[20H_END] END AS [20],
CASE WHEN b.[21H_START] < b.[21H_END] THEN  b.[21H_START] ELSE b.[21H_END] END AS [21],
CASE WHEN b.[22H_START] < b.[22H_END] THEN  b.[22H_START] ELSE b.[22H_END] END AS [22],
CASE WHEN b.[23H_START] < b.[23H_END] THEN  b.[23H_START] ELSE b.[23H_END] END AS [23]


from
(
/*Step 2  - calculating minutes from starttime and endtime */

select a.*,

/**Calculating the number of minutes worked from start_time MIN **/
    CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 0 and a.[0] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0   THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[0] END AS [0H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 1 and a.[1] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[1] END AS [1H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 2 and a.[2] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[2] END AS [2H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 3 and a.[3] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[3] END AS [3H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 4 and a.[4] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[4] END AS [4H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 5 and a.[5] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[5] END AS [5H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 6 and a.[6] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[6] END AS [6H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 7 and a.[7] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[7] END AS [7H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 8 and a.[8] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[8] END AS [8H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 9 and a.[9] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[9] END AS [9H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 10 and a.[10] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[10] END AS [10H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 11 and a.[11] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[11] END AS [11H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 12 and a.[12] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[12] END AS [12H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 13 and a.[13] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[13] END AS [13H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 14 and a.[14] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[14] END AS [14H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 15 and a.[15] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[15] END AS [15H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 16 and a.[16] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[16] END AS [16H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 17 and a.[17] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[17] END AS [17H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 18 and a.[18] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[18] END AS [18H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 19 and a.[19] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[19] END AS [19H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 20 and a.[20] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[20] END AS [20H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 21 and a.[21] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[21] END AS [21H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 22 and a.[22] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[22] END AS [22H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 23 and a.[23] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[23] END AS [23H_START],

/**Calculating the number of minutes worked from END_time MIN **/
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 0 and a.[0] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[0] END AS [0H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 1 and a.[1] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[1] END AS [1H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 2 and a.[2] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[2] END AS [2H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 3 and a.[3] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[3] END AS [3H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 4 and a.[4] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[4] END AS [4H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 5 and a.[5] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[5] END AS [5H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 6 and a.[6] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[6] END AS [6H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 7 and a.[7] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[7] END AS [7H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 8 and a.[8] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[8] END AS [8H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 9 and a.[9] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[9] END AS [9H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 10 and a.[10] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[10] END AS [10H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 11 and a.[11] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[11] END AS [11H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 12 and a.[12] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[12] END AS [12H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 13 and a.[13] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[13] END AS [13H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 14 and a.[14] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[14] END AS [14H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 15 and a.[15] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[15] END AS [15H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 16 and a.[16] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[16] END AS [16H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 17 and a.[17] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[17] END AS [17H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 18 and a.[18] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[18] END AS [18H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 19 and a.[19] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[19] END AS [19H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 20 and a.[20] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[20] END AS [20H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 21 and a.[21] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[21] END AS [21H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 22 and a.[22] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[22] END AS [22H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 23 and a.[23] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[23] END AS [23H_END]



from
(--Step 1:
/*to determine 1 or 0 using the start and end hour 
    If time falls in the respective hour = 1
if time doesnt fall in the respective hours = 0*/
SELECT 

--DISTINCT 

[EMPLOYEENAME], 
[DEPARTMENT],
[SHIFTA_start],
CASE WHEN  [SHIFTA_START] !='' OR SHIFTA_START != NULL THEN CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103) ELSE NULL END AS SHIFTA_START_con,
CASE WHEN  [SHIFTA_START] !='' OR SHIFTA_START != NULL THEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103))  ELSE NULL END AS StartTime_HOUR,
CASE WHEN  [SHIFTA_START] !='' OR SHIFTA_START != NULL THEN DATEPART(mi,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103))  ELSE NULL END AS StartTime_min,

[SHIFTA_end],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_END] !='' OR SHIFTA_end != NULL THEN CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_END],17),103) ELSE NULL END AS SHIFTA_END_con,
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_END] !='' OR SHIFTA_end != NULL THEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103))  ELSE NULL END AS EndTime_HOUR,
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_END] !='' OR SHIFTA_end != NULL THEN DATEPART(mi,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103))  ELSE NULL END AS EndTime_min,


CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 0 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [0],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 1 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [1],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 2 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [2],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 3 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [3],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 4 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [4],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 5 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [5],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 6 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [6],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 7 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [7],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 8 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [8],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 9 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [9],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 10 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [10],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 11 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [11],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 12 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [12],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 13 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [13],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 14 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [14],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 15 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [15],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 16 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [16],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 17 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [17],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 18 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [18],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 19 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [19],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 20 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [20],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 21 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [21],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 22 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [22],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 23 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [23]
from [TableName].[dbo].[TMS_PEOPLE]

where ShiftA_Start != '' and ShiftA_End !='' 
and SHIFTA_start != '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' and SHIFTA_end != '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'

)a

)b
```

Comment: You have an error in datecolumn to start with.  http://prntscr.com/b1y8kd
08-31 -> 09-01 and you have 01-09

Comment: The other question is what hour columns do you expect to be populated? Do you realize that they do not represent one full day now?

Comment: @Skoffer  Currently, SHIFTA_START and SHIFTA_END are the time they start work and end work respectively. And if they work overnight, 23 columns are empty in SQL. Only when the employee start and end work on the same day, the columns will then be populated.

Comment: @Skoffer  So right now, eg: employee work from 3rd jan 2130 to 4th jan 0730, I want to populate the columns from 3rd jan 2130 to 3rd jan 2359. 4th jan can be ignored and need not to be populated.